# Will an apex class run if test methods are specified inside that

Tags: apex, unit-test

I'm having an apex class in which I've written both the controller logic and test class methods. So that I don't need to write a separate test class for that apex class. In case, my test class fails in the sandbox and I'm trying to deploy to production. My question here is :

1. If I deploy the class to production will this run ?
2. If I chose "Run specified test class" and I dont include this class in that and then deploy. Will this run ?

Comment: Why don't you want to write the extra test class? If you already have the methods then writing the class shouldn't be to much work. I don't think what you want is possible, but even if it is you should probably stick to the best practice and create a separate test class.

Comment: Yes. But out of curiosity, I wanted to know what would happen if we do like this

Answer (score 3):

Inline Apex tests, where the unit tests are included in the body of the class being tested, have not been allowed on Salesforce since API version 28.0. You should not create or deploy new code on API 28.0, which is ~6 years old at this point. By doing so, you're buying into six years of old bugs and behaviors that have long-since changed, and locking yourself out of six years of improvements to the platform and to Apex. You're essentially creating technical debt by doing so!

So the answers to your questions, assuming that you're *not* making this very risky choice to deploy code on an ancient API version, are "No" and "No". Assuming you are working on a semi-recent API version, you won't be able to deploy the code at all, because inline test methods are not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

There was a point in time where Salesforce allowed test methods to be defined in the same class as the actual code, but that point in time ended about 6 years ago.

From [Apex Test Code Segregation](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/04/apex-test-code-segregation.html) on the official Salesforce blogs

> Starting with the Summer ’13 release of the platform, Apex test methods need to be created in test classes.  (A “test class” is one marked with the @isTest annotation.)  Test methods will no longer be able to compile in the same class as your regular executable code.

Summer '13 is API version 28.0 (the current API version is 46.0)

If you try to add an `@isTest` annotated method into a class that isn't also annotated with `@isTest`, you'll get an error

> Defining type for IsTest methods must be declared as IsTest

If you go and add the `@isTest` annotation to the class, then you'll get the following error when trying to make a new instance

> System.TypeException: Cannot call test methods in non-test context

That happens even if the method you're trying to call isn't static, or isn't annotated with `@isTest`. It happens even if you try to call the *constructor*.

Since API 28.0, I believe that Salesforce only considers the classes annotated with `@isTest` when running tests (as part of a deployment, through the developer console, etc...)

Trying to run a non-test class by specifying specific unit tests to be run as part of a deployment won't produce any errors on its own, but it also won't provide any coverage.